# Apache Ignite failing on startup

Tags: ignite

I've configured Ignite in standalone mode as writethrough mod cach. When it is starting fails and have this exception
It is creating a long file name that linux don't allow it create that folder

```
Got exception while starting (will rollback startup routine).
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start processor: GridProcessorAdapter []
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startProcessor(IgniteKernal.java:1787)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1066)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1757)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1679)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1121)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1015)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:921)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:840)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:710)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:679)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:353)
    at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:365)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to create page store work directory: /home/user/apache-ignite/work/db/0_0_0_0_0_0_0_1_lo_10_0_0_100_10_0_0_203_10_99_0_5_127_0_0_1_198_18_0_1_198_18_0_129_198_18_0_65_198_18_2_1_2604_3d09_679_2b00_0_0_0_1dc7_wlp0s20f3_2604_3d09_679_2b00_8332_15b9_3cd0_484_wlp0s20f3_2604_3d09_679_2b00_ae91_a1ff_fe7e_63ba_enxac91a17e63ba_2604_3d09_679_2b00_d986_6638_3c47_cd7c_wlp0s20f3_2604_3d09_679_2b00_e8bf_ac63_b39_630e_enxac91a17e63ba_47501
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.ensureDirectory(IgniteUtils.java:9971)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridLocalConfigManager.<init>(GridLocalConfigManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.start(GridCacheProcessor.java:618)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startProcessor(IgniteKernal.java:1784)
    ... 11 more
```

I try to conffigure an enitye read and write by ignite

Comment: Please attach full stack trace - there should be the root cause deeper down.

Answer (score 0):

The directory's name is based on the "consistent ID" of the node. If you don't specify one, it creates one based on your IP addresses and port numbers. In your case, the created name is too long.

The workaround is to define your own consistent ID:

```
export IGNITE_OVERRIDE_CONSISTENT_ID=node00
bin/ignite.sh
```

(There's already a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/apache/ignite/issues/10648) about this.)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the workaround proposed by @stephen-darlington above.

An additional workaround which is favorable for servers but not local environments on laptops or workstations is to disable RFC8981 temporary IPv6 addresses.

Another heavier workaround may be appropriate for local sandbox environments: disable Java's use of IPv6:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

There is also a Jira ticket in the Ignite project covering this. If this issue affects you, please vote on the Jira ticket and add additional symptoms/impacts/workarounds to the ticket comments.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-17985